# pytorch+tensorboard error " AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'items' "

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, tensorboard

Good afternoon.
I want to log the loss of the train using the tensorboard in pytorch.
I got an error there.

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'items'
```

I want to solve this error and check the log using tensorboard.
Here I show my code.

```
l_mse = mseloss(img,decoder_out)
writer.add_scalars("MSE",l_mse,n_iter)
```

`img` is real image in GAN and `decoder_out` is Generator output.
then I have error blow.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 39, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 22, in main
    solover.train(dataloader)
  File "path to my file", line 239, in train
    writer.add_scalars("MSE",l_mse,n_iter)
  File "/~~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/tensorboard/writer.py", line 378, in add_scalars
    for tag, scalar_value in tag_scalar_dict.items():
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'items'
```

I tried

```
writer.add_scalars("MSE",l_mse,n_iter).eval()
writer.add_scalars("MSE",l_mse.item(),n_iter)
writer.add_scalars("MSE",l_mse.detach().cpu().numpy(),n_iter)
```

but still not work well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling for `writer.add_scalars` with a `s`. From [Pytorch Tensorboardx](https://tensorboardx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) documentation you can see that this function expects a `dictionary` as input.

```
 add_scalars(main_tag, tag_scalar_dict, global_step=None, walltime=None)
```

- **tag_scalar_dict** (dict) – Key-value pair storing the tag and corresponding values

```
writer = SummaryWriter()
r = 5
for i in range(100):
    writer.add_scalars('run_14h', {'xsinx':i*np.sin(i/r),
                                    'xcosx':i*np.cos(i/r),
                                    'tanx': np.tan(i/r)}, i)
writer.close()
```

Use `writer.add_scalar` instead

> To log a scalar value, use `writer.add_scalar('myscalar', value, iteration)`. Note that the program complains if you feed a PyTorch tensor. Remember to extract the scalar value by `x.item()` if x is a torch scalar tensor.

```
writer.add_scalar("MSE", l_mse.item(), n_iter)
```

Comment: thank you for ansering! I try to do ```writer.add_scalar("MSE", l_mse.item(), n_iter)```but still same error.

Comment: Can you place here the output of `l_mse.size()` ?